# Passing a NSString to NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a hard time figuring out how to pass a NSString to a NSObject class.

I have a .h and .m file which is a NSObject and I need to pass a string from a UIViewController.

This is what I tried when pushing the view:

```
        NSString *urlString = @"TextHere";
        WXClient *svc = [[WXClient alloc]init];
        svc.urlOne = urlString
```

And then, I am retrieving it this way:

```
    @interface WXClient : NSObject {

    NSString *urlOne;
    }
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlOne;
```

and of course, then on the .m :

```
@synthesize urlOne;
```

Then to use the NSString:

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlOne];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    //blah blah blah blah... :D
}];
```

But for some reason it is returning null. I am able to use this method from viewController to viewController but to NSObject is not working :(

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You never allocate and initialize an instance of `WXClient`.

Comment: And you need a newer tutorial. You do not need the explicit ivar or `@synthesize` line for your `urlOne` property.

Comment: I suggest reviewing some of the basics of Objective-C.

Comment: "how to pass a NSString to a NSObject File." -- You don't pass a string to a file.  You might *write* a string in a file, but I don't think that's what you have in mind.

Comment: what I mean by file is that I have a .h and .m files set to be a NSObject.

Comment: Implement prepareSegue method and set property to destination view controller

Comment: Your WXClient class is a subclass of NSObject. That is not the same thing as being an NSObject.

Comment: Ok, then why I can't pass a string?

Comment: If you literally do this `NSString *urlString = @"TextHere"; WXClient *svc; svc.urlOne = urlString;` in that order, with no intervening statements, then clearly you will get nothing, because `svc` is nil.

Comment: And `NSString *urlString = @"TextHere"; WXClient *svc = [[WXClient alloc] init]; svc.urlOne = urlString;` will do no better, since that instance of WXClient is almost certainly not the instance you'll be referencing when you try to retrieve the value.

Comment: (You can't pass a string because you don't know what you're doing.)

Comment: Well, how come it works perfectly when passing from ViewController to ViewController? Whats the difference from passing from a UIViewController class to NSObject class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        WXClient *svc = [[WXClient alloc]init];
        NSString *urlString = @"TextHere";
        svc.urlOne = urlString;
```

Sorry didn't read question properly

Comment: WXClient is not a viewController. Is an NSObject.

Comment: a view controller is a nsobject too.

Comment: Sure, but I am passing it to a NSObject directly, not a UIViewController. Look at my code above.

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz Have you imported WXClient.h in your VC?

Comment: Then import it & check... @MichaelOrtiz

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. The way it works is that I have a UIViewController which as a WXManager. When the viewController launches, it calls the manager which then the manager calls the WXClient. So when I push the view, I want to change a url that is on the WXClient, so that the manager can then pass it into the UIViewController. Do you get what I mean? Thanks

Comment: The problem with the above answer is that it creates an instance of WXClient that is unrelated to the one that will be referenced to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing/presenting view controller throug `segue` and you want to send some data to destination view contrller. Like you want to set some property, you need to implement this method. `prepareForSegue:sender:`.
In it you you can get destination `viewController` and set whatever property you want to.

```
  - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"weatherWXID"]) {
            WeatherViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
            NSString *urlString = @"TextHere";
            WXClient *svc = [WXCLient new];
            svc.urlOne = urlString
            vc.wxclient = svc;
        }
    }
```